# How to Determine Common superview of two views in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I was given this question by a friend of mine and I am not able to figure out the answer on my own. I have already tried to Google around but am finding answers for the iOS platform instead.

Perhaps I could Googling the wrong terminology, I would like guidance on how to find the answer. If it comes to a scenario such that the Android OS/ abstraction does the implementation for the developer, I would like to know what as well.

How to Determine Common superview of two views in Android?

Comment: What means "common superview of two views"? Are you looking for a parent container that contains both or are you looking for an ancestor in class inheritance? Also talking 80% of your question about how you don't find the answer etc doesn't make the question clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [View.getParent()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getParent()) from both Views until you find the lowest common ancestor in the n-ary tree of Views.

Comment: It will be just SOME common ancestor, not the lowest :) In most cases (when views have different levels in views tree) this method just returns root view.

Comment: If there are two views. We can first traverse view1 parents and keep their references in  a HashMap until view1.getParent() returns null. Then we can check view2 parents one by one and return the first parent that is present in the HashMap. This should give a lowest common ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA doesn't have multiple inheritance so yo cannot do it by `extends` but there is a way to do it through interfaces. Just define an interface with methods that you want each of the view subclasses to have and then your view subclasses have to implement this interface.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if there is existing method to do that in Android, but it is not difficult to write your own method. Common superview is just a lowest common ancestor (LCA) of these two views in views tree. Finding of LCA is standard algorithmic problem and there are many algorithms with different asymptotics to solve it.